# Error creating git branch - Offset and length were out of bounds for the array

Tags: git

I am trying to create git branch from master using Visual Studio 2017.

Getting below error:

Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

Already tried solution as suggested in git - Create Branch From Tag Error to close all VS/Team Explorer instances, and clean cache folder C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache. Then try again.

No luck with the suggested solution, looking for help/guidance to resolve

Answer (score 0):

If the issue persists (and you are not able to upgrade to [Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/)), you would have to fall back to command-line.

That means:

- installing the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)
- `cd c:\path\to\repository`
- `git switch -c newBranch master`

That is a workaround, for sure, but [other](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/offset-and-length-were-out-of-bounds-for-the-array/859044) [similar](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-checking-out-git-branches/835059) bug reports in Visual Studio are without answer or cannot be reproduced.